# Delegate of type 'required'

Tags: ios, delegates, cllocationmanager

What in ios is a `required` delegate method?
Example:

```
CLLocationManagerDelegate

locationManagerDidPauseLocationUpdates:
Tells the delegate that location updates were paused. (required)
```

The question is related to the last word: '(required)'

I know that there are optional delegate methods, but what happens if I do not implement
all of the required delegates?

Especially I have not implemented the above method in my App which uses the LocationManager,
SDK is ios6, target = ios5.

Could my App crash if I do not implement that method? 
I recently ported to ios6, but till now it did not crash!
Was that luck that the method had not been called, or is required a recommendation?

**Update:**

The info above is from ios6.1 Docu set.

When I open the ios6.1 header file

LocationManager.h:

```
 *  Discussion:
 *    Invoked when location updates are automatically paused.
 */
- (void)locationManagerDidPauseLocationUpdates:(CLLocationManager *)manager __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_6_0);
```

There is no hint for required, they are all under the @optional tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could crash is as close as we can get. Generally it means that if you don't implement it something won't work, but the documentation isn't as accurate as it could be. In some cases the class using the delegate doesn't check that the delegate actually implements the specified method so whenever it was called you'd get an exception. So, if the documentation says it's required it's best to implement it, even if your implementation is an empty method.

Comment: Tell me one thing is it possible to don't implement the required method declared in protocol and you don't define it in the class who conforms that protocol?

Comment: It's possible to not implement required methods, but it's not a good idea (and you'll usually get a compile warning about it)

Comment: Only warning comes and crash?

Comment: Can Crash Occur if we don't implement required method?

Comment: Yes, it can. You should assume that it will crash.

Comment: It means if I don't implement a required method I will get warning? I said to you because in interview interviewer asked me that he don't get any warning too if he doesn't implement the required method. :)

Comment: If you say you implement a protocol but there is no implementation of a required method then you will get a warning (it may be hidden after the first compilation if the class isn't reanalysed)

Comment: Ok i got it the description

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, "`locationManagerDidPauseLocationUpdates`" is called on iOS 6 (and newer) OS'es to inform your app that the location isn't changing and that it's shutting down to save power.

On iOS 5, this delegate method won't get called but if you implement it, it *will* get called in iOS 6.

If you target iOS 6 (instead of iOS 5), you'll get a compiler warning if you didn't implement any "required" delegate methods.

Comment: in LocatioManager.h there is no hint for required: